# Innerproduct in space of holomorphic functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a problem with the following exercise (6.4.5) in "Foundations of real analysis" by Avner Friedman:
Let $D$ be the disc $|z|<1$ in the complex plane. Denote by $H^2(D)$ the linear subspace of $L^2(D)$ consisting of all functions holomorphic in $D$. Prove that $\{ \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi }}z^{n-1} \}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H^2(D)$. A hint is given:

The n:th fourier coefficent is equal to:

$a_n=\lim_{r \to 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi n}} \frac{r^{2n}}{2i}\int _{ |z|=r } \frac{f(z)}{z^{n}}dz$

This is where my confusion starts! What inner product does this space have? They give the above expression for $a_n=(\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi }}z^{n-1}, f(z) )$. But is not the complex $L^2$ inner product equal to $(\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi }}z^{n-1}, f(z) )=\int _{ |z|=1 } \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi } }z^{n-1}\overline{f(z)}dz$? 
How did they end up with the expression above and what is the innerproduct in this space?

Comment: The inner product is the one inherited from the $L^2$ space, so $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_D f(z) \overline{g(z)} d\lambda$, where $d\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure in the plane (so just $dxdy$, really). You now have to calculate the inner products of the elements of that basis (polar coordinates will probably be very useful) and show that it spans the whole space.

Comment: using the formula for $a_n$ given I had no problem showing that the sequence is orthonormal. But I don't understand how the autor came up with the expression $a_n$ for the innerproduct and this is what I wonder!

Comment: He's probably cheating*: Since $\overline z = 1/z$ on the unit circle I'm sure you can get his formula by pretending that your functions are defined on a slightly larger circle. Then you let the radius $r$ vary and prove that the limit converges to what you want on the unit circle. The reason to put $1/z^n$ into the formula is because then you get the coefficients of the series expansion of $f$ on the unit circle by Cauchy's formula. (* I say "cheating", but I think it's very clever.)

Comment: Ok! So I'm using this to vertify Parsevals formula but what is even the $L^{2}$ norm of $f$ given in the coefficents in the power series expansion of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner product on the space is the one induced by $L^2(D)$,

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \iint_D f(z)\overline{g(z)}\,dx\,dy.$$

Writing $h_n(z) = \sqrt{\dfrac{n}{\pi}}\cdot z^{n-1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we can check that $\{ h_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is an orthonormal system:

$$\begin{align}
\langle h_n, h_m\rangle &= \iint_D \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}}\cdot z^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{m}{\pi}}\cdot \overline{z}^{m-1}\,dx\,dy\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{nm}}{\pi} \iint_D z^{n-1}\overline{z}^{m-1}\,dx\,dy\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{nm}}{\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} r^{n+m-2} e^{i(n-m)\varphi} r\,d\varphi\,dr\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{nm}}{\pi} \int_0^1 r^{n+m-1}\,dr\cdot \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n-m)\varphi\,d\varphi}\\
&= 2\delta_{nm}\sqrt{nm}\int_0^1 r^{n+m-1}\,dr\\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{nm}}{n+m}\delta_{nm}\\
&= \begin{cases} 0 &, n \neq m\\ 1 &, n = m,\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

where $\delta_{nm}$ is the Kronecker-$\delta$.

I'm not sure whether the hint is intended to be used here, since the computation using the area integrals is straightforward enough.

However, if $f(z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k$ is the Taylor expansion of $f$, the Cauchy integral formula gives us

$$c_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{f(z)}{z^n}\,dz$$

for all $0 < r < 1$. We expect that the Fourier expansion with respect to the $h_n$ conicides with the Taylor series, i.e. $c_{n-1} = \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}} a_n$. So

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n}} c_{n-1} &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n}\,i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{f(z)}{z^n}\,dz\\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n}\,i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{f(z)\overline{z}^n}{r^{2n}}\,dz\\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n}\,ir^{2n}} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} f(z)\overline{z}^n\,dz \tag{Stokes}\\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n}\,ir^{2n}} \iint_{\lvert z\rvert < r} n\cdot f(z)\overline{z^{n-1}}\,d\overline{z}\wedge dz\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}} r^{-2n} \iint_{\lvert z\rvert < r} f(z)\overline{z^{n-1}}\,dx\,dy\\
&= r^{-2n} \langle \chi_{\{\lvert z\rvert < r\}}\cdot f, h_n\rangle_{L^2}.
\end{align}$$

Taking the limit $r\to 1$ shows that indeed

$$a_n = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n}}c_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n}\,i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{f(z)}{z^n}\,dz = \lim_{r\to 1} \frac{r^{2n}}{2\sqrt{\pi n}\,i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{f(z)}{z^n}\,dz.$$

The completeness of the orthonormal system $\{h_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ then follows by the connection between $a_n$ and the Taylor coefficients that is established by the hint: If $\langle f, h_n\rangle = 0$ for all $n$, then all Taylor coefficients vanish, hence $f\equiv 0$.

> but what is even the $L^2$ norm of $f$ given in the coefficents in the power series expansion of $f$?

From the above relation between the Fourier coefficients and the Taylor coefficients, it follows that

$$\lVert f\rVert_{L^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\pi}{k+1} \lvert c_k\rvert^2;\qquad \langle f,g\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\pi}{k+1} c_k\overline{d_k}$$

if $f(z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k$ and $g(z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty d_kz^k$.

Since the power series are locally uniformly convergent in the disk, for any given $0 < r < 1$ we can interchange summation and integration in the integral over $\{z : \lvert z\rvert < r\}$ to obtain the same relations in a different way.